# how can I use WebtiledLayer in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin forms I am going to show the path of an airplane according to its latitude and longitude. So for this purpose, I want to use ArcGIS Esri to show a map with a specific level of details.

Here is my code but **I cannot set the level of details to map what should I do?**

```
WebTiledLayer myBaseLayer = new WebTiledLayer("https://stamen-tiles-{subdomain}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{level}/{col}/{row}.jpg");
Basemap layerBasemap = new Basemap(myBaseLayer);
Map myMap = new Map(layerBasemap);
MyMapView.Map = myMap;
```

The following works but I don't want to use it because of some limitations.

```
myMap = new Map(BasemapType.Imagery, Latitude, Longitude, 15);
MyMapView.Map = myMap;
```

Comment: So is your problem that you want to zoom to a certain part of the map?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the level of details and add it to `TileInfo`, then pass the `TileInfo` as a parameter when you create a `WebTiledLayer`:

```
private void Initialize()
{
    LevelOfDetail item = new LevelOfDetail(1, resolution, scale);

    List<LevelOfDetail> mainLevelOfDetail = new List<LevelOfDetail>();
    mainLevelOfDetail.Add(item);

    TileInfo mainTileInfo = new TileInfo(
                DPI,
                TileInfo.ImageFormat.PNG24,
                mainLevelOfDetail,
                mainOrigin,
                mainOrigin.getSpatialReference(),
                tileHeight,
                tileWidth
        );

    // Create the layer from the URL and the subdomain list
    WebTiledLayer webTiledLayer = new WebTiledLayer(
                mainUrl,
                SubDomain,
                mainTileInfo,
                mainEnvelope);

    // Create a basemap from the layer
    Basemap layerBasemap = new Basemap(myBaseLayer);

    // Create a map to hold the basemap
    Map myMap = new Map(layerBasemap);

    // Add the map to the map view
    MyMapView.Map = myMap;
}
```

Comment: I do not know exactly what value I have to set these parameters: "Resolution", "Scale", TiltHeight, TileWidth and MainEnvelope .

Comment: @mostafahosseini Have a look at this [blog](https://www.twblogs.net/a/5b8bf8d92b717718832f7eb9) may help.